# Are "polite" and "politics" etymologically similar?

Tags: etymology

I read of the words ["polite"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polite) and ["politics"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/politics) on Wiktionary. They originate from Latin word for "smooth" and Greek word for "state", so superficially i concluded they have nothing in common.

But the connection makes sense. Wiktionary defines "politics" also as "Political maneuvers or diplomacy between people, groups, or organizations, especially involving power, influence or conflict". To be successful with politics an individual has to be polite, woo the crowd, be a nice guy. Rude and hostile people in such environment are quickly marginalized and shut up.

Were "polite" and "politics" connected etymologically at some point?

Comment: Looks like Mr. Shiny and New has it covered, but just wanted to note that "politics" has its own adjective: "politic."

Comment: Is this about political correctness by any chance :p ? "Être poli" in French does mean to be polite.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are not related.

> Polite (en) <-  [Latin politus "polished"](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=polite&allowed_in_frame=0) <- Latin polio "polish" <- *pel- "to strike" (Proto-Indo-European) ([see Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polio#Latin))
>
> Politics (en) <- [Politic (en)](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=politic&allowed_in_frame=0) <- Polis "city" (ancient Greek) <- *tpolH- "fortification" (Proto-Indo-European) ([see Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CF%8C%CE%BB%CE%B9%CF%82#Ancient_Greek))

Comment: I answered this even though it's somewhat GR because Etymology is on topic, and the trail of references isn't super easy to find.

Comment: looks like it is a “false cognate” / linguistic coincidence - great article about this https://starkeycomics.com/2019/06/06/fantastic-false-cognates/

Answer (score 0):

I think they stem from the same root. The Greek word *politika* means "affairs of state" and hardly connoted anything like the necessity to be *polite* (from Latin *politus*, "refined, organized"). The connection can be seen, however, in the Late Latin *polita* (organized government), which serves a junction point for the *state* and *organized* meanings.

The information above has taken from http://etymonline.com which is excellent resource for such researches.

Comment: And general reference.

Comment: This is wrong, as explained by Mr. Shiny and New's answer above.